# Autoencoder of CNN - decrease or increase filters?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

In an Autoencoder based on CNN, will you increase or decrease the number of filters between layers  ? As we compress the information, I was thinking of decreasing.

Example here of the encoder part where the number of filters is decreased at each new layer, from 16 to 8 to 4.

```
x = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='encoder_1a')(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding='same', name='encoder_1b')(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='encoder_2a')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding='same', name='encoder_2b')(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 4, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='encoder_3a')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding='same', name='encoder_3b')(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always the case that the filter sizes are reduced or increased with increasing number of layers in encoder. In most examples of encoder I have seen of convolutional autoencoder architectures the height and width is decreased through strided convolution or pooling, and depth of layer is increased (filter sizes are increased), kept similar to last one or varied with each new layer in encoder. But there is also examples where the output channels or filter sizes are decreased with more layers.

Usually autoencoder encodes input into latent representation/vector or embedding that has lower dimension than input that minimizes reconstruction error. So both of the above can be used for creating [undercomplete autoencoder](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/autoencoders.html) by varying kernel size, number of layers, adding an extra layer at the end of encoder with a certain dimension etc.

##### Filter increase example

In the image below as more layers are added in encoder the filter sizes increase. But as the input `28*28*1 = 784` dimension features and the flattened representation `3*3*128 = 1152` is more so another layer is added before final layer which is the embedding layer. It reduces the feature dimension with predefined number of outputs in fully connected network. Even the last dense/fully connected layer can be replaced by varying the number of layers or kernel size to have an output `(1, 1, NUM_FILTERS)`.

[image]

##### Filter decrease example

An easy example of filters decreasing in encoder as the number of layers increase can be found on [keras convolutional autoencoder](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) example just as your code.

```
import keras
from keras import layers

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
```

##### References

- https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/autoencoders.html
- https://xifengguo.github.io/papers/ICONIP17-DCEC.pdf
- https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html